# Ploting Lineplot for Each Category using Groupby and For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to make a `subplot` of `lineplot` for each product using `groupby` for the following dateset:

```
#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'product': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'sales': [4, 7, 8, 12, 15, 8, 11, 14, 19, 20],
                   'avline': [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17]})

# Glimpse of DataFrame
df
    day product sales   avline
0   1   A   4   9
1   2   A   7   9
2   3   A   8   9
3   4   A   12  9
4   5   A   15  9
5   1   B   8   17
6   2   B   11  17
7   3   B   14  17
8   4   B   19  17
9   5   B   20  17
```

I'm trying the following code with `for` loop because I'd like to add `axvline` for each product later:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for k, v in df.groupby('product'):
    v.plot(x='day', y='sales', label=k, ax=ax)
```

However, I'm getting the following plot, and I want separate lineplot for each product.
[image]

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to add a vertical line? Please explain that point in detail.

Comment: Hi @r-beginners, I have added another column and I want to that in a vertical line.

Comment: Is there a single vertical line, or one for each day?

Comment: One for each one as they differ for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'product': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'sales': [4, 7, 8, 12, 15, 8, 11, 14, 19, 20],
                   'avline': [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17]})

colors = ['b', 'r']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2) # 1 row, 2 columns 

for i, (k, v) in enumerate(df.groupby('product')):
    v.plot(x='day', y='sales', c=colors[i], label=k, ax=ax[i])
    # add a vertical line 
    ax[i].axvline(v.iloc[0]['avline'], linestyle="--")
```

It gives:

[image: plots]

Comment: Hi @bb1, thank you for help. I liked the 1st one. Now, if I want to add the vertical line, how should I proceed?

Comment: Added another column `avline`

Comment: @Roy I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood, to generate multiple lineplots for each product:

First one is using seaborn.FacetGrid, which will provide you with multiple line plots for each product category.

```
import seaborn as sns
graph = sns.FacetGrid(df, col ="product")
graph.map(plt.plot, "day", "sales")
plt.show()
```

This will give you an output like this:
[image]

Or else, you can also use plt.plot to give you multiple lineplots.

```
lst = df['product'].unique()
for ls in lst:
    df1 = df[df['product'] == ls]
    plt.plot('day','sales',data=df1)
    plt.title(f'Product {ls}')
    plt.show()
```

[image]
This will create a new df and then plot it seperately.

Personally, I prefer the first option more.

Comment: Hi @Prats, thank you so much. How should add the vertical line from the `avline` column?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you mean by that, but from what I understood, add this line of code above the plt.show() in seaborn example to get that vertical line:

graph.map(plt.plot,"avline","sales")